# What does selecting an OS in VirtualBox actually do?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

In the setup process for a new virtual machine, VirtualBox presents several different OS types and versions to choose from:

[image: types of machines available]

[image: windows versions available (partial)]

[image: linux versions available (partial)]

I'm curious as to what VirtualBox actually does when you select an OS. I'm sure, for example, that it wouldn't present the same hardware to a Windows 3.1 guest as it would to Windows 7. What I'm less clear on, however, are the potential differences between, say, a Linux and a BSD guest: if they're both designed to run on the same hardware, then what optimizations could VirtualBox possibly make if it knows which OS it's hosting?

In other words, *what types of changes does VirtualBox make to the VM when you select an OS?*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Take a look at the relevant file in the VirtualBox source code:

https://www.virtualbox.org/browser/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Main/src-all/Global.cpp

It looks like it's mainly choosing a few things:

- Reasonable default sizes for RAM, hard disk, etc.
- A set of virtual hardware that the OS presumably has built-in and/or stable drivers for (e.g., look at the old Windows versions, which get Sound Blaster 16).
- A set of miscellaneous system features (I/O APIC, EFI, PAE, VT-x/AMD-V extensions, etc.) that the OS supports or requires.

Ultimately, you could configure all of these items yourself via the Settings dialog box -- VirtualBox is just offering a default configuration that should work without a lot of fussing around.

Comment: It also makes a VM more easily distinguishable in the list of VM's by the icon

Answer (score 2):

Although, [not all the answers:](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html)

> For "Operating System Type", select the operating system that you want
>   to install later. The supported operating systems are grouped; if you
>   want to install something very unusual that is not listed, select
>   "Other". Depending on your selection, VirtualBox will enable or
>   disable certain VM settings that your guest operating system may
>   require. This is particularly important for 64-bit guests (see the
>   section called “64-bit guests”). It is therefore recommended to always
>   set it to the correct value.

I would venture to guess it also helps VirtualBox decide what VirtualBox drivers it presents to the guest OS for both Generic and final drivers during the build and deployment process.

I cannot see this is documented anywhere more thoroughly.